# Get containers running a given image version

Tags: docker

I need to manage my server's cache of Docker images to make sure I don't fill the disk.

I'd like to get a list of all Docker images which are currently not being used by a running container. I can get a list of running Docker containers with the following:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
fdbe4426220a        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         5 days ago          Running                       compassionate_brown
```

I can also get a list of local Docker images with the following:

```
$ sudo docker images 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              latest              07f8e8c5e660        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu              12.04.5             ac6b0eaa3203        3 weeks ago         132.5 MB
```

Based on the above info, I can conclude that I can `rmi` the `ubuntu:12.04.5`, which is no longer necessary as nothing is running based on it.

Parsing this with command line tools kind of sucks, and the `--filter` method for `ps` doesn't seem to enable me to search based on image name. There's no way I can see to output a more machine-readable list so I can parse things with a script or something to delete old images.

Is there a way provided by Docker to clean up old unused images before they fill the disk? This seems to be a big problem for organizations who automate releases, so I'm assuming that there *is* in fact a way of managing this. I'm on Docker latest, 1.6, on an Ubuntu 14.04 host.

Comment: by the way, do not forget that `docker ps`will only show the running containers, you may have some containers that ended with an error and were supposed to be running, `docker ps -a` will show all your containers (or, if you just want the id, like the answer said `docker ps -aq`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There's no way I can see to output a more machine-readable list so I can parse things with a script or something to delete old images.

Both `docker ps` and `docker images` have a `-q` option that makes them only output a list of hashes rather than tables.  Combining this with [`docker inspect`'s templates](http://container-solutions.com/2015/03/docker-inspect-template-magic/) and some common shell utilities gives us:

```
#!/bin/bash
comm -23 <(docker images -q --no-trunc | sort) \
         <(docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' | sort -u)
```

which outputs the hashes for all unused images.